# Send multi-line signature to Metamask via web3js

Tags: web3js, metamask

Checked all the similar questions suggested and couldn't find an answer, unfortunately.

Is there a way to send a **multi-line message** to metamask via **web3.eth.personal.sign** as the first parameter? (The problem is how to get multiple lines, not how to actually send a message there)

A more eloquent example of my question can be seen in the image attached. There are multiple paragraphs on separate lines: 'Welcome to OpenSea!', 'Click "Sign" to sign in..." etc.

Thanks a lot!

[image: Multi line message in metamask request signature event]

Answer (score 1):

You can either use \n or use `instead of '' or "" when you send the message. The option with` takes the spacing in the content into consideration (in js).